# What is the purpose of a balun and a unun in a feed line?

Tags: antenna-construction, feed-line, balun

I have never understood how a balun or a unun works and under which situation I need to use either of them in an antenna feed line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A balun matches a balanced load to an unbalanced line, but it can also do other useful things. A current balun can present a high impedance to common-mode signals, which will help reject noise. Common mode signals are the same on both conductors, so are not "balanced" or differential.

An unun is an impedance transformer, usually `4:1` or `9:1`, which matches an unbalanced antenna to a feedline. A `9:1` transformer is often used for an end-fed half wave antenna.

This document by Jim Brown (K9YC) is long, but tremendously helpful in understanding baluns, chokes, and reducing RF noise:

["A Ham's Guide to RFI, Ferrites, Baluns, and Audio Interfacing"](http://audiosystemsgroup.com/RFI-Ham.pdf)